# A good programming language is a conceptual universe for thinking about programming

Tags: quotations

Could someone please explain this quote?

> A good programming language is a conceptual universe for thinking about programming.
>   -- Alan Perlis

I tried looking for the meaning of "conceptual universe" but cannot find the meaning that would fit in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

**The meaning of this quote is:**

What we need is not just another programming language but a conceptual universe for thinking about software development, embodied in a kind of language that is new to computer science -- a language that will bridge the gap between programming and software development at large.